# Excel returning dates instead of values in excel column

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have an excel importer that takes the data from an excel worksheet and fills a Data Table.
My function is returning a value like "1/3/1900 9:36:00 AM" when the cell actually contains "3.4" 
The entire excel sheet is formatted as "Text" and I cant change the format due to some client constraints.

my sample function:

```
DataRow dataRow = table.Rows[i];

B= new B();
string value = (dataRow[index] != null) && (!dataRow[index].ToString().Trim().Equals("NA")) ?   dataRow[index].ToString().Trim() : null;
A= (value != null && value.Length!=0) ? value : A;
B.Name = A;

value = (dataRow[++index] != null) && (!dataRow[index].ToString().ToString().Trim().Equals("NA")) ? dataRow[index].ToString().Trim() : null;
B.Name += " " + value;
```

The connecting string is

```
string strConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
            + "Data Source='" + filePath + "';"
            + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;'";
```

I am using IMEX=1 even then also I am not able to find out exact error.

```
----------
Returning           --------  Ideally should return

1/3/1900 9:36:00 AM  ---------->> 3.4

1/3/1900 12:00:00 PM ---------->> 3.5

1/4/1900 2:24:00 AM  ---------->> 4.1.1

1/4/1900 2:24:00 AM  ---------->> 4.1.2

1/4/1900 2:24:00 AM  ---------->> 4.1.3

1/4/1900 4:48:00   ------------>> 4.2
```

Sample from excel sheet where Column A is like below:

5/16/2013

9:14:00 AM
Para.

3

3.1

3.2

3.3

3.4

3.5

4.1

4.1.1

4.1.2

4.1.3

4.2

4.3

5

5.1

5.1.1

5.1.2

Comment: "My function is returning a value"  Which function?  What's the code there?  `IMEX=1` is _supposed_ to treat all data as text, so I'm confused why 3.4 is getting translated to a date/time.

Comment: Hi Stanley, The excel sheet column 1 that is Index 0 is like one data is in date the other is in time while rest as 3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4  sample of excel is :        5/16/2013

9:14:00 AM


Para.
3
3.1
3.2
3.3
3.4
3.5
4.1
4.1.1
4.1.2
4.1.3
4.2

Comment: Can you add that to the question so that it can be formatted properly?

Answer (score 1):

Change the cells type in the excel.

1. Select all the column values
2. right click and select Format cells
3. Choose number as type

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the issue by formatting the cells as *general* or *number* or something else that isn't *date* (which is how the cells are currently formatted).

Use a line like the following to format as general:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "General"
```

where `A1` represents the range you're looking to format. You can expand that to cover all the cells you're concerned with.

Good luck!